# Creating a form within a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

Okay so I have the following function and HTML to go with it which is COMPLETELY working however I am looking to add extended functionality. I am wondering if its possible to make a form appear with the close_game function that popups on the screen?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/FTBV5ee.png]

Blurred out in the above image is confidential information that I cannot show but I am wondering if in between the "Are you sure you want to close the game?" and "This action cannot be undone." I could put a form there and than when the Close Game button in the button right this form would be submitted and information put into the database.

Does anyone know of a good way to do this at all or if this is even possible?
(Something to note is this site is based of the laravel framework)

```
<div id="myModal_close" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close icon-remove" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Close Game</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Are you sure you want to close the game <span id="modal-game-close-name"></span> (Serial Num: <span id="modal-game-close-serial"></span>) ?</p>
        <p>This action cannot be undone.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
        <button id="confirm_close" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger">Close Game</button>
    </div>
</div>


function close_game(game_name, serial) {
       $('#modal-game-close-name').html(game_name);
       $('#modal-game-close-serial').html(serial);
       $('#confirm_close').off('click.close_game').on('click.close_game', function() {
          $.ajax({
             url: '/game/' + serial + '/',
             type: 'PUT',
             success: function (data) {
                $('#alerts').html('<p class="alert alert-success">Successfully closed ' + serial + '</p>' + $('#alerts').html());
                $('#r' + serial).hide();
             },
             error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#alerts').html('<p class="alert alert-error">A problem occured while closing ' + serial + '</p>' + $('#alerts').html());
                $('#r' + serial).hide();
             }
          });
       });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
<div id="myModal_close" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close icon-remove" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Close Game</h3>
 </div>
<div class="modal-body">
<form id="myForm">
    <p><input type="text" id="username"></p>
    <p><input type="text" id="email"></p>
   <p><input type="password" id="password"></p>
</form>
   </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
    <button id="submit" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh its as easy as that hmmm... but I dont think that would work when hitting the close game button would it?
I would need to add stuff in the javascript function wouldn't I to make it submit the form? or no?

Comment: Yes of course you will have to edit your JavaScript to submit data when the Submit button is clicked. Give it a try